# Button background color in webpart

Tags: html, css, sharepoint-2013

I'm using an html file with the following css / html - in the browser this button comes through as expected - orange - but when uploaded to a sharepoint webpart it has a white background - what could be the reason for this?

Are there other properties I could use to enforce this styling?

```
.clickBut {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #ffa500;
    border-radius: 100px;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
</head>
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Refresh|Reset" onclick="resetRefresh();" class="clickBut" />
...
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test background-color: #ffa500 !important;

Comment: perfect - why does this help?

Comment: because if you use a plug-in is easier than to that property it has already been assigned a !important. you have to use it to override it in your turn, to the !important css rules apply only if you overwrite it with another otherwise takes precedence over everything.